# Pair device in bluetooth android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect another android device by Bluetooth, So first I paired the devices and then I tried sending the request for another device.

When I called the system bluetooth settings screen, I am able to pair the another device

```
    Intent btSettingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(btSettingsIntent, Pair_Request);
```

When I tried to pair by programmaticaly, I'm getting this dialogue and entered pair digit in my device but no response in another device

```
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(strAddress);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST");
    intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE", device);
    intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT", 0);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I got this image in device, when I type pair number, I'm not getting anything in another deivce

[image]

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: are you sure your device is discoverable.?

Comment: Yes, it is. Im querying all the bluetooth device and trying to pair the device ? but no response in another device. We can connect the device without pairing? guide me to achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

if the device is already paired , then you can use

```
if(device.getBondState()==device.BOND_BONDED){

        Log.d(TAG,device.getName());
        //BluetoothSocket mSocket=null;
        try {


            mSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG,"socket not created");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{

            mSocket.connect();

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            try {

                mSocket.close();
                Log.d(TAG,"Cannot connect");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Socket not closed");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

for the MY_UUID use

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

the above code snippet is just to connect your device to an A2DP supported device.
I hope it will work. tell me if not.

Comment: May i know , what is UUID "0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB", how do i get for my device?

Comment: Im getting exception, " Service discovery failed", what does it mean? what i made wrong?

Comment: @kumaand : either both devices are not paired or one of your devices is not discoverable. cross check it.

Comment: Thanks, Device is paired, both are discoverable too...Is i want to write app for both client and server for this? UUID want to match on both side to acheive this?